# How to interpret ordinal regression coefficient (between two variables)?

Tags: regression-coefficients, ordinal-data

I trying to read a table of results looking at usage duration of health & fitness apps, by people of different ages, genders and extraversion levels.

I have come across this table, but don't understand the **coefficient column**.

[image]

Can someone please put one of the coefficient values into words for me? Does for example, gender being -0.247 mean, that gender has minus 25% correlation with health app duration of usage? Whereas age has 28% correlation?

Comment: I don't know how gender could be ordinal. It must be a factor, in that case it would be good to know which gender is the reference. Also, there is no correlation with factor variables.

Comment: Hmm. yeah. that's why I got confused. How about extraversion, how would one interpret that?

Comment: Gender is a predictor variable and need not be ordinal. Like Age, which is likely interval-scaled.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your ordinal regression is the proportional odds logistic regression, the coefficients are log-odds-ratios. Concretely, the coefficient of -0.247 for gender means that a change in gender, while leaving all other variables constant, changes the odds for belonging into a higher usage category by a factor of $\exp(-0.247)$.

Also, for age, which is presumably given in years, the coefficient of 0.284 means that each additional year of age increases the odds by a factor of $\exp(0.284)$.

There should also be one or more intercept terms which determine the boundaries between usage categories.

Comment: As a side note, it seems that different software output very different coefficients given the same data and the same ordinal model, so it may be wise to have a look at the documentation when interpreting the coefficients. See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/592680/why-do-statsmodels-python-and-mass-r-output-different-intercept-values-for-m/592710 or https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/548358/ordinal-regression-python-vs-spss