# Why do statsmodels (Python) and MASS (R) output different intercept values for my ordinal regression model?

Tags: r, python, regression-coefficients, statsmodels, ordered-logit

From the same dataset and same ordinal regression model, I get two different intercept outputs with Python's statsmodels library ([`OrderedModel`](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/examples/notebooks/generated/ordinal_regression.html:) function) and with R's MASS package ([`polr`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/MASS/versions/7.3-58.1/topics/polr) function), and I don't understand why.

I don't know if the problem originates from a software issue or from a statistical issue/interpretation, so in doubt I ask it here.

Anyway, here's the polr output:

```
Call:
polr(formula = satisfaction ~ gender, data = u, Hess = TRUE, 
    model = FALSE)

Coefficients:
             Value Std. Error t value
genderwomen 0.1183     0.1204  0.9833

Intercepts:
                                 Value    Std. Error t value 
not satisfied|somehow satisfied   -1.5239   0.1185   -12.8592
somehow satisfied|very satisfied   1.0782   0.1159     9.2994

Residual Deviance: 5076.661 
AIC: 5082.661
```

And here's the statsmodels output:

```
        Optimization terminated successfully.
         Current function value: 0.975156
         Iterations: 79
         Function evaluations: 141
                             OrderedModel Results                             
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:           satisfaction   Log-Likelihood:                -2538.3
Model:                   OrderedModel   AIC:                             5083.
Method:            Maximum Likelihood   BIC:                             5100.
Date:                Tue, 18 Oct 2022                                         
Time:                        07:42:53                                         
No. Observations:                2603                                         
Df Residuals:                    2600                                         
Df Model:                           3                                         
==================================================================================================================
                                                     coef    std err          z      P>|z|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
C(gender, Treatment(reference='men'))[T.women]     0.1183      0.120      0.983      0.325      -0.118       0.354
not satisfied/somehow satisfied                   -1.5240      0.119    -12.859      0.000      -1.756      -1.292
somehow satisfied/very satisfied                   0.9564      0.023     42.259      0.000       0.912       1.001
==================================================================================================================
```

As you can see, all values are similar, except the "somehow satisfied/very satisfied" one  (1.0782 in polr, 0.9564 in statsmodels), which is a bit confusing.

Why are they different?

If it can help, here's some code to reproduce the results above:

In R:

```
library(MASS)
#creating the dataset
h_ps = c("men", "not satisfied", 61)
f_ps = c("women", "not satisfied", 366)
h_ms = c("men", "somehow satisfied", 158)
f_ms = c("women", "somehow satisfied", 1304)
h_ts = c("men", "very satisfied", 83)
f_ts = c("women", "very satisfied", 631)    
data = as.data.frame(rbind(h_ps, f_ps, h_ms, f_ms, h_ts, f_ts))
names(data) <- c("gender", "satisfaction", "Freq")
#function to create a raw dataset from the crosstable, taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/30863433/3889011
tableinv <- function(x){
  y <- x[rep(rownames(x),x$Freq),1:(ncol(x)-1)]
  rownames(y) <- c(1:nrow(y))
  return(y)}
u = tableinv(data)
u$`satisfaction` <-  factor(u$`satisfaction`, order = TRUE, 
                      levels = c("not satisfied", "somehow satisfied","very satisfied" ))
u$gender <- relevel(factor(u$gender), ref="men")
#ordinal regression model
m <- polr(satisfaction ~ gender, data = u, Hess=TRUE)
summary(m)
```

In Python:

```
import pandas
from statsmodels.miscmodels.ordinal_model import OrderedModel
#creating the dataset
crosstab = pandas.DataFrame(columns=["not satisfied", "somehow satisfied", "very satisfied"],
                index=["men", "women"],
                data=[[61,158,83],[366,1304,631]])
s = crosstab.stack([0])
raw_data = s.index.repeat(s).to_frame(index=False)
raw_data.columns = ["gender", "satisfaction"]
raw_data
raw_data["satisfaction"] = pandas.Categorical(raw_data["satisfaction"], ordered=True,
                                              categories=["not satisfied", "somehow satisfied", "very satisfied"])
#ordinal regression model
mod_prob = OrderedModel.from_formula("satisfaction ~ C(gender, Treatment(reference='men'))", raw_data, distr='logit')

res_prob = mod_prob.fit()

print(res_prob.summary())
```

Additional information:

- R version 4.1.3, MASS_7.3-58.1
- Python 3.10.2, statsmodels 0.13.2

Thanks,

Comment: I guess this is https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/548358/ordinal-regression-python-vs-spss  statsmodels uses a parameterization that forces threshold to be monotonic

Comment: @Josef This is exactly the problem, I was answering my own question before seeing your comment!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the answer, this is exactly the same issue described here (Python vs. SPSS): [Ordinal Regression: Python vs. SPSS](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/548358/ordinal-regression-python-vs-spss), that is:

> The Python coefficients are the logarithms of the differences

(while R handles the coefficient the same way SPSS does.)

Basically, to find  the same coefficient as in R, we have to add the exponentiated coefficient ("somehow satisfied/very satisfied", i.e.                   `exp(0.9564)`) to the "base" coefficient ("not satisfied/somehow satisfied", i.e. `-1.5240`), that is `-1.5240+exp(0.9564) == 1.078311`, which is very close to what `polr` returns.

Let's check with the exact values in Python to be sure:

```
import numpy as np
r_value = 1.0782 #output value from polr
print(res_prob.params) #let's check what the parameters look like
print()
python_value = res_prob.params[1] + np.exp(res_prob.params[2])
python_value = round(python_value,4) #as the value from R is probably rounded
if (r_value == python_value) == True:
   print(r_value, "==", python_value)
   print("it works!")
```

output:

```
gender_                             0.118348
Not satisfied/somehow satisfied    -1.523956
somehow satisfied/very satisfied    0.956351
dtype: float64

1.0782 == 1.0782
it works!
```

Thanks to [@josef](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/14187/josef) for his comment that confirms what I suspected!

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this. This is IMO a serious flaw in `statsmodels`: The behaviour is counter-intuitive, user-unfriendly, and, most importantly, undocumented. As `OrderedModel` is still experimental, maybe you could ping the developers and point it out to them?

Comment: It imposes nonnegativity/monotonicity and prevents that probabilities for a level can become negative. That's a recommendation in several books and articles. You can recover the reparameterized version as in the answers here. The only disadvantage is that it is difficult to get analytical derivatives, statsmodels currently uses numerical derivatives (finite diff).

Comment: However I opened https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/8449

Comment: BTW: it is documented but maybe not in the obvious places, e.g. https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/examples/notebooks/generated/ordinal_regression.html before line 7, https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.miscmodels.ordinal_model.OrderedModel.transform_threshold_params.html

Comment: @Josef Thanks for sharing. It is really well hidden and confirms my first two points (and only slightly weakens the third). I consider it suboptimal software design. Is there a reason why an API user might be interested in raw, non-transformed values? I understand (now) why they are used internally, but why bother the user with implementation details?

Comment: Because statsmodels reports estimated parameters and associated inference. If a user wants a different parameterization (beta coefficients, eform, ...), then they need to be recovered from the estimated parameters. I don't think thresholds are of primary interest, the relevant outcome is predicted probabilities and effect of explanatory variables.

Comment: (not directly applicable here) In many cases with single parameters we use endpoint transformation for confidence intervals because the transformed parameters are closer to  normally distributed. example exponential of parameters in Logit and Poisson.

Comment: In this case a confidence interval for a linear threshold might be "negative", i.e. smaller than the previous threshold. Linear threshold confidence intervals do not impose non-negativity either. The statsmodels implementation with exponentiated increments would have monotonic confidence intervals.

Comment: However, in this case we cannot use endpoint transformation for confidence intervals because there are multiple parameters.

Comment: `make incremental exp parameterization optional` is on my wishlist, but didn't get around to implement it yet https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/7069 Not a very high priority for me.

Comment: and one more:  In generalized ordered Logit linear slope parameters can also differ by choice not just the intercept. This also can result in negative probabilities, see e.g. Williams https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/8444

Comment: @josef Thank you so much for the detailed explanation and for the ticket. As an end user, it was a bit confusing that statsmodels offers a different output from other statistical software. I don't have the whole picture, but personally, a different output is something I can totally live with, as long as it is well-documented -even if I understand that it can be more problematic for other use cases. I guess the answer here may be some additional documentation (or maybe some optional parameters to allow a similar output from R or SPSS for people who need it?). Anyway, thanks again.