# Ordinal regression using statsmodels OrderedModel - basic interpretation

Tags: python, ordinal-data, statsmodels, ordered-logit, ordered-probit

I want to run an ordinal regression in Python. My dependent variable describes a medical condition in an ordered manner (e.g. 0 = healthy, 1 = affected, 2 = very affected, 3= severely affected). I was trying to run this regression using the OrderedModel from statsmodels.miscmodels.ordinal_model. However, I'm struggling to find a good guide or info on how to interpret the model outputs, so I made a test dataset. This is the code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from statsmodels.miscmodels.ordinal_model import OrderedModel

np.random.seed(40)

# Generate a test dataset
n_samples = 100000
categories = [0, 1, 2, 3]
y = np.random.choice(categories, size=n_samples, p=[0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.2])
x_field1 = np.random.rand(n_samples) * 10
x_field2 = np.random.rand(n_samples) * 10 + (y)  # Correlated

data = {
    'eid': np.arange(1, n_samples + 1),
    'y_field': y,
    'x_field1': x_field1,
    'x_field2': x_field2
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Convert y_field to ordered categorical var
df['y_field'] = pd.Categorical(df['y_field'], categories=categories, ordered=True)

test = OrderedModel(df["y_field"], df[["x_field2"]], distr="probit")  
res_log = test.fit(method='bfgs')
print(res_log.summary())

test = OrderedModel(df["y_field"], df[["x_field2"]], distr="logit")  
res_log = test.fit(method='bfgs')
print(res_log.summary())
```

As you can see in the code, I generated an independent variable x_field2, which is positively correlated with my dependent variable. I also ran both logit and probit as I wanted to test and compare both.

The output I get from summary() is as follows:

```
                             OrderedModel Results                             
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:                y_field   Log-Likelihood:            -1.3089e+05
Model:                   OrderedModel   AIC:                         2.618e+05
Method:            Maximum Likelihood   BIC:                         2.618e+05
Date:                Tue, 08 Aug 2023                                         
Time:                        16:38:10                                         
No. Observations:              100000                                         
Df Residuals:                   99996                                         
Df Model:                           4                                         
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          z      P>|z|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
x_field2       0.1226      0.001    106.536      0.000       0.120       0.125
0/1           -0.1029      0.008    -12.372      0.000      -0.119      -0.087
1/2           -0.1084      0.005    -21.376      0.000      -0.118      -0.098
2/3           -0.1073      0.005    -21.196      0.000      -0.117      -0.097
==============================================================================

                             OrderedModel Results                             
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:                y_field   Log-Likelihood:            -1.3095e+05
Model:                   OrderedModel   AIC:                         2.619e+05
Method:            Maximum Likelihood   BIC:                         2.619e+05
Date:                Tue, 08 Aug 2023                                         
Time:                        16:38:12                                         
No. Observations:              100000                                         
Df Residuals:                   99996                                         
Df Model:                           4                                         
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          z      P>|z|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
x_field2       0.2033      0.002    105.479      0.000       0.200       0.207
0/1           -0.1778      0.014    -12.983      0.000      -0.205      -0.151
1/2            0.4017      0.005     76.547      0.000       0.391       0.412
2/3            0.4022      0.005     76.814      0.000       0.392       0.412
==============================================================================
```

I can see that x_field2 is positively and significantly correlated, which I would expect. But how do I read 0/1, 1/2 and 2/3 (the coefficients)? I thought they must be something like the log-odds of an increase from 0 to 1, 1 to 2, 2 to 3, etc. in dependence of x_field2 (something like a breakdown of the results for each step in the ordinal variable). But then I would expect positive numbers throughout, right?

What also really puzzles me is - I tried shifting the category numbers, e.g. 1-4 instead of 0-3, or 2-5, and the signs, rather than just the sizes of the coefficients, partly change.

I would greatly appreciate any help in understanding how to read these outputs.

Comment: I think that if you study the math in [probit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probit_model) and [logit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logit) you will find that negative coefficients are possible.

Comment: I recommend you watch a lecture on how the breaks in the dependent variable work. While it is Bayesian and implemented in R, which are not what you are currently doing, you may benefit from watching [*Statistical Rethinking 2023 - 11 - Ordered Categories*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VVQaIkom5D0) in order to better understand the math.

Comment: If you want to go Bayes, but stick with Python, you can use PyMC (among other packages I'm sure). See [`OrderedProbit`](https://www.pymc.io/projects/docs/en/latest/api/distributions/generated/pymc.OrderedProbit.html) or [`OrderedLogistic`](https://www.pymc.io/projects/docs/en/latest/api/distributions/generated/pymc.OrderedLogistic.html).

Comment: shifting the category numbers or relabeling should not affect the results, as long as the ordering is preserved. OrderedModel should only take the ordering but not the values of the dependent variable into account. If that is not the case, then something is wrong.

Comment: Briefly, the level transitions coefficients (2|3 etc.), **except the first one**, are logarithms and can easily be negative. Check this answer and the comments for a more detailed explanation: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/592710/169343

Comment: Thank you for the helpful comments, and the link to this informative statistics series. I understand now - not only are the coefficients logarithmic, but also cumulative. 
I'll check back here in a few days in case there is an answer I can accept to close this.

Comment: You can also answer your own question. This might help other users who encounter the same problems in the future.